# Combo box inside Data grid template column is showing system.data.datarowview

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

In my project i have a data grid with three combo box template columns. and the combo box is data bind using xaml. But when I run the project combo box is showing `system.data.dataRowView` . here is my code for the data grid cell

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category" Width="*" x:Name="categoryColumn">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="categoryBox"
                            IsEditable="True"
                            fa:FocusAttacher.Focus="True"
                            controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                            controls:TextBoxHelper.SelectAllOnFocus="True"
                            controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Category"
                            MaxDropDownHeight="125"
                            SelectionChanged="CategoryBox_OnSelectionChanged"
                            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                            DisplayMemberPath="{Binding CategoriesCollection.Columns[1]}"
                            SelectedValuePath="{Binding CategoriesCollection.Columns[0]}"      
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.CategoriesCollection.DefaultView, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Why it is not showing the correct data. Can anyone suggest me a way to fix this

Comment: Get rid of the `CategoriesCollection.` in the binding path for `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` It should just be `{Binding Path=Columns[1]}`

Comment: Are you still getting `system.data.dataRowView`

Comment: yes, nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `DisplayMemberPath="{Binding CategoriesCollection.Columns[1]}"` is failing because it has to be given a relative source binding just as the `ItemsSource` binding you present.

Either provide a proper binding for Displaymember path

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.CategoriesCollection.Columns[1], 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"`
```

or hard code it to be the target property name which is sought.